# How to push notification from rest client for testing purpose

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, rest-client

Hi I am trying to push the notification from rest client to android app. I am doing like below -

```
URL - https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Method - POST
Headers - Authorization: my_server_key
```

I always get this message

> Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
>   Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.002
>   Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing & last I am using correct server api key.

Please assist & thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this blog post http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2012/10/java-push-notifications-for-ios-and.html but it is in Java

Comment: @HarshaVardhan thanks but it does not have any explanation regarding push the notification from rest client

Comment: I said it is in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set this values in the header then it is working fine for me.

Below is the header key & value.

A) Authorization: & it value likes key=API_KEY

B) Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

Push notification uses `Web Socket`. You cannot do this using `HTTP protocol` unless you have a server side implementation set up to respond to your request through Web Socket.

Answer (score 0):

```
  I hope you are done with your request but it will help to others

You have to send like this
In head
-------
Headder             Value

Authorization      key=your value
Content-Type       application/json

In Body
-------
Something like this
{
  "registration_ids" : ["Your id"],
  "data" : {
    "message":"Your message"
  }
}
```

Hope it will help