# how to get SNS working in Android?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification

how to get SNS working in Android?

We have an app that sends SNS messages to iOs apps already (I personally am only working with the App side). And have extended it to send Android messages. It works fine for iOS and thinks it is sending to Android correctly but no message ever actually shows up on the Android device.

I am registering with the backend by getting the Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID and sending that to the web service that registers it with Amazon SNS.

I have turned on all the permissions that I can (I don't need to specifically ask for permission do I?, how would I do that).

Basically the setup we have is I hand our web service a device id and it registers with Amazon and the web service sends the notifications out (but I am never seeing them).

Is there anything else I need to do or check on the client side?

Comment: Also, on the web service side it works the first time or thinks it does. And then when sending a second time it will report "Endpoint is disabled". And then if the android unregisters/registers again it will "work" one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SNS for push messaging on android instructions is the same as normal GCM on android.

You must follow the directions here:

[GCM Getting Started](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) - covers the google console set up and will provide you with the :

1. SenderId, for use in the android app code.  (This is the Google Console's Project #)
2. the api key, for use in SNS server setup

[Implementing GCM Client](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html.) - covers client library, getting the registration ID, setting up a wakeful service and broadcast receiver for creating notifications or whatever you'd like you app to do when it receives a push.

You should also read thru amazon's documentation [Getting Started with Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html) which summarizes the the previous two links.

> I am registering with the backend by getting the Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID and sending that to the web service that registers it with Amazon SNS.

This is not correct.  By using the GCM client library, call the following methods to get the real registration ID (sns likes to call them an endpoint) that you can send to the web service that registers it with Amazon SNS. There should be no need to use `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` at all for push on android.

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(someContext);
String registrationId = gcm.register(senderId);
```

> I have turned on all the permissions that I can (I don't need to specifically ask for permission do I?, how would I do that).

see [Implementing GCM Client](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html.) for the required permissions that you must include in your AndroidManifest.xml.  And no,  you don't need to specifically ask for permission since it would be in the AndroidManifest.xml but you could ask the user on first app start with a dialog or some other UI.  You may also choose to let the user disable push for you app via a settings screen if your app has one.

> Is there anything else I need to do or check on the client side?

You should confirm that you are able to get registration ids (perhaps some logging)?
And then with those ids, test your implementation.  Here is a question that was asked a while ago that will help you use a rest client to send pushes with your registration ids and api_key (SNS login not needed).

[How to push notification from rest client for testing purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008860/how-to-push-notification-from-rest-client-for-testing-purpose)